# Laravel custom validation and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, validation

The validation on my Laravel 4.2 project was done with Ardent package. After going to Laravel 5.5 I have eliminated Ardent and wanted to do Laravel's native validation with form requests.

The problem I have is that the Ajax call was validated before like this:

```
public function postRegisterAjax(A)
{
    try {
         ...
    } catch (ExceptionBag $e) {
        $msg = $e->getMessageBag()->all(':message');
        $status = Status::ERROR;
    }

    return $this->responseJson($status, $msg);
}
```

Now I introduced `UserValidationRequest` class and I would like Ajax call to throw me an error message without the need to reload the page. In order to do that, I need to forward status and message as Json response.

I somehow tried to do that with after validation hooks, but it doesn't work:

```
protected function getValidatorInstance()
{
    $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        \Log::info($validator->errors());

        $msg = $validator->errors();
        $status = Status::ERROR;

        return response()->json(['response' => [
            'status' => $status,
            'msg' => $msg,
        ]]);
    }

    return $validator;
}
```

The code fails on `return response()` saying that `Method passes does not exist` (`Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php:96`).

Does anyone know what seems to be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Laravel 5.x version (not sure), `failedValidation()` method was introduced in form requests instead of what Laravel 4.x had as `response()`.

I resolved my issue by tailoring the response to my needs by overriding that method in my form request:

```
public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $status = Status::ERROR;
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(["response" => [
            'msg'    => $validator->errors()->all(':message'),
            'status' => $status
        ]]));
    }

    return response()->json(["response" => [
        'msg'    => 'User successfully registered',
        'status' => Status::SUCCESS
    ]]);
}
```